# Sorting through images but need to stop on the last image instead of closing out the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the function currently,

```
  $("#btnNextImage").click(function (e) {
                 var win = window.opener.parent; 
                 win.postMessage('next', '*');
                 window.close(); //close current tab before opening new tab
                e.preventDefault(); 
            });
```

This will go through the images when clicking on the btnNextImage but when I get to the last image of the results, the window closes out. I want it to check to see if the image is last and if so prompt an alert asking whether or not the user wants to stay on the window or close it.

Comment: Want to remind you that SO is not a free coding service. A tip that I can give you is to have a number ID on each image, and then check which one you are on, and if you are on the last one have a special `if` that catches that.

Comment: So how would you know it is the last? We have no clue how you get that from the information you provided.

Answer (score 0):

Put an Id on each of your images, then check if its the last, with a simple if($("#lastId"))

Then use the confirm method prompt users if you need to close windows

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp